# Not able to execute a batch file in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, batch-file

I am trying to execute a batch file in a jsp which resides in the TOMCAT Server. jsp is in webapps/ROOT/test.jsp, batch file is also placed in the same location as webapps/ROOT/test.bat. Following is my JSP code:

```
<%
    Process p=Runtime.getRuntime();
    String scriptExecute = "cmd /c start  test.bat";
    try {
        p.exec(scriptExecute);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
```

On executing this jsp what I get is blank page. Kindly provide me a solution for this.

Comment: There's no output in the snipped you posted.

Comment: Simply starting a new process won't put any output from that process into your web page.  Is that the goal?  Or do you just want to run the process and you were worried that it might not be running because you didn't see any output in your browser after attempting to invoke it?

Comment: Actually i tried the same using a servlet as well. Same response. There is something missing.

Answer (score 0):

Runtime.getRuntime() returns Runtime not Process so correct it..

```
<%

    String scriptExecute = "cmd /c start  /<name of your project>/WebContent/<name of batch file>";
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(scriptExecute);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
```

I think this would help you..

Comment: Thanks for the response..I tried the above snippet. Same response.Nothing gets executed. I have tried the same in java It worked. I don know why it is not getting executed in jsp.